# Unable to produce bibliographic references in Emacs+AUCTex

Tags: bibtex, emacs

I am trying to include references in a document of mine but I have a problem.

First of all I use Emacs+AUCTex in Ubuntu.

I have the following `.tex` and `.bib` files:

**Document File**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}


\usepackage{parskip}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}


\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\setmainfont
[
    Ligatures=TeX,
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*,
    BoldFont=*Bold,
    ItalicFont=*It,
    BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt,
    Mapping=tex-text
]{GFSArtemisia}

\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia.otf}

\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

\setmathfont[range=\varnothing]{Asana-Math.otf}

\setmathfont[range=\int]{latinmodern-math.otf}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{lettrine}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Information Theory Project}

\author{Name}

\date{}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\lipsum[1]

\end{abstract}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\lipsum[1-2]

Cite this book: \cite{Cover}

\end{multicols}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

**Bibliography File**

```
@BOOK{Cover,
    Author       =        "Thomas M. Cover and Joy A. Thomas",
    Title        =        "Elements of Information Theory",
    Edition      =        "2",
    Year         =        "2006",
    Publisher    =        "John Wiley and Sons",
}
```

My problem is that in Sharelatex it works without issues but when I compile it with Emacs it doesn't work.

I get the following warnings:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `Cover' undefined on input line 25.

No file "Project".bbl.
[1] (./Information Theory Project.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Add a citation in your `.tex` file (e.g. `\nocite{*}`) and then run BibTeX. Does it help?

Comment: There are a number of problems in your example code. 1) your code is not minimal and doesn't even contain a citation, so we cannot reproduce your error 2) there is a point at the end of the `Publisher` field in the bibliography file, remove it 3) run `"LaTeX"`, `"BibTeX"`, `"LaTeX"` (AUCTeX will default to the correct operation every time you press `C-c C-c`) and you'll have the file compiled correctly. Basically you didn't run BibTeX.

Comment: @karlkoeller sorry I have already doing that! I just didn't write it in the MWE. I will edit it.

Comment: Removing the dot after the `Publisher` field does not solve the problem?

Comment: @karlkoeller no it doesn't. I have tried previously with the dot, or with a comma or without them both and it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you run BibTeX?

Comment: I don't know what to say, then. If you follow @giordano instructions it should work. Last try: delete the `.bbl` file, if any.

Comment: @giordano 1) I have removed everything that may be of no use before posting I think that all these are useful. 2) I have tried without it before and there was the same result. 3) I have tried compiling the `.tex` with `C-c C-c` and then compiling the `.bib` with the same keys and after that again the `tex` but it doesn't work either. I don't know if I am doing something wrong. :/

Comment: The only problem in your code is the dot (`.`) after the `publisher` field. After I change it to `,` the code compiles correctly.

Comment: This *is* a minimal example: `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}
\cite{Cover}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Bibliography}
\end{document}`.
Anyway, you have to issue `C-C C-c` always in the same buffer, that of the main .tex file.  AUCTeX will always suggest you the right operation, nothing more (apart from the period in the `Publisher` field).

Comment: @Mico The dot was just an experiment in case it worked. I will edit so not to confuse people.

Comment: @giordano I am compiling the main file with `C-c C-c` but it just says that "there was unresolved citations". Nothing more.

Comment: I ask again: did you run `BibTeX`?

Comment: @giordano I think so but because I am a new AUCTex user how exactly should I had done it?

Comment: `C-c C-c bibtex RET` or press the button with a book icon (`Run BibTeX` tooltip) in the toolbar.

Comment: @giordano it worked! Thank you very much! If you want you can form it into an answer to accept or if it is too elementary I can delete the question. To my defense I hadn't realised I had to actually write "bibtex". :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a general rule, in order to produce the bibliography you have to run the bibliography engine (`bibtex` in your case)  after compiling the main document.

You get that warning because you didn't run `bibtex`.  In AUCTeX, you can

- only issue <kbd>C-c C-c RET</kbd>, generally AUCTeX is able to suggest the right operation to do
- force running `bibtex` with: <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> `bibtex` <kbd>RET</kbd> should AUCTeX fail to detect the program to run (but this is not the case)
- press the book icon in the toolbar (`Run BibTeX` is its tooltip)
- go to the menu `Command` > `BibTeX`

Comment: I don't know since when, but nowadays, AUCTeX offers `C-c C-a` (`TeX-command-run-all`), which will run LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX and LaTeX again.  Sometimes even accompanied by Makeindex ...